# RESTul config routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

## Hey everybody, I'm have a problem when debug rails. I want to create API to Add, edit, delete  Students , with RESTul

## This is my routes.rb

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHbsn.png)

I can't show json by api.mysite.com:3000/humans

Comment: It would be easier to help if you described the problem a bit more –what are you trying to do, what do you expect to happen, what routes and controllers do you have set up? – and maybe copy the error message from the server log rather than putting in a picture, so it's easier to google in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Routing Error**

This is due to you are requesting the URL which is doesn't exist in routes.rb file

Please check your `config/routes.rb` in order to solve your problem.

Comment: Can you show your routes and explain what are errors your are getting.